# Write a mongo query to count the data where similar data in array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, mongodb-query, mongo-collection

**Sample data:** there are multiple similar collection:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(301),
   
    "telecom" : [ 
        {
            "countryCode" : {
                "value" : "+1"
            },
            "extension" : [ 
                {
                    "url" : "primary",
                    "value" : [ 
                        "true"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "modifiedValue" : {
                "value" : "8887778888"
            },
            "system" : {
                "value" : "phone"
            },
            "useCode" : {
                "value" : "Home Phone"
            },
            "value" : {
                "value" : "8887778888"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "extension" : [ 
                {
                    "url" : "primary",
                    "value" : [ 
                        "true"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "modifiedValue" : {
                "value" : "abc@test.com"
            },
            "system" : {
                "value" : "email"
            },
            "useCode" : {
                "value" : "work"
            },
            "value" : {
                "value" : "abc@test.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Issue:** I want to cont the collection where `telecom.system.value = email` and `countryCode` doesn't exist in the email part object. here I am attaching  a script but I need one line query

```
var count = 0,i;
  db.getCollection('practitioner').find({"telecom.system.value":"email"}).forEach(function(practitioner){
    //print("updating : " +practitioner._id.valueOf())
    telecom = practitioner.telecom.valueOf()
    for(i= 0;i<telecom.length;i++){
        if(telecom[i].system.value === 'email' && telecom[i].countryCode){
        count+=1;
             }
    }
  });
  
    print(" Total count of the practitioner with country code in email object: "+count)
```

Above mention, the script is working fine and the output is as I expected. but the script is not optimised and I want to write in a single line query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try aggregation method `aggregate()`,

**Approach 1:**

- `$match` condition for `countryCode` should exists and `system.value` should be `email`
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `telecom` array and check both condition, this will return expected elements
- `$size` to get total element from above filter result
- `$group` by null and count total

```
var result = await db.getCollection('practitioner').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      telecom: {
        $elemMatch: {
          countryCode: { $exists: true },
          "system.value": "email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      count: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$telecom",
            cond: {
              $and: [
                { $ne: [{ $type: "$$this.countryCode" }, "missing"] },
                { $eq: ["$$this.system.value", "email"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      count: { $sum: "$count" }
    }
  }
]);

print("Total count of the practitioner with country code in email object: "+result[0].count);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C5CKjpjiBOr)

---

**Approach 2:**

- `$match` condition for `countryCode` should exists and `system.value` should be `email`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `telecom` array
- `$match` to filter document using above conditions
- `$count` to get total elements count

```
var result = await db.getCollection('practitioner').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      telecom: {
        $elemMatch: {
          countryCode: { $exists: true },
          "system.value": "email"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$telecom" },
  {
    $match: {
      "telecom.countryCode": { $exists: true },
      "telecom.system.value": "email"
    }
  },
  { $count: "count" }
]);

print("Total count of the practitioner with country code in email object: "+result[0].count);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gjBjP_R5703)

> I have not tested the performance but you can check and use as per your requirement.